# Purge Cloudflare cache on file behind apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, browser-cache, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare to cache my static content. I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite all pages requests to index.php to use the "page name" as variable in JS.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

I want to purge index.php after code update but here is the problem, each page/url is treated like a unique url ignoring the fact that different urls served by the same index.php.

ie:

http://example.com/page1

http://example.com/page2

are actually example.com/index.php.

How can I "notify" Cloudfalre about this rewrite rule so I can purge just index.php to take affect in the entire platform and not purging each url individually.

Thanks,
Vadim

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly CloudFlare has no knowledge of `index.php`, given that this is a rewrite on your origin.

CloudFlare sees requests for `example.com/page1`, `example.com/page2` etc but as far as it knows these are completely different pages. Therefore I don't see how you can avoid purging all URLs without completely reorganising your URL targets.

Comment: This is exactly the situation and the question: How can I notify cloudflare about the setup(mod_cloudflare or some other scheme)?

Comment: My point is, even if you could, you still need to purge each URL - I can't see how this is avoidable. Your apache server is like a black box, CloudFlare never gets a request for index.php so can't possibly purge it